# Alinear texto de un botón en android xml

Tags: android, xml

He creado un botón y le he puesto como background una imagen, pero al colocar el texto sobre el boton se coloca en una posicion no deseada, hay alguna forma de alinear el texto para quede de forma centralizada con la imagen, ya he probado con la propiedad gravity no funciono, el boton es de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo del boton es este:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/botones"
        android:text="Empezar"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/btn_color_text"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Y en que posicion exactamente es que quieres el texto?

Comment: Un poco mas arriba, para que coincida centrado con la tabla de la imagen, he probado dandole algo de padding pero no funciona.

Comment: Y por que no simplemente colocas el `botón` sin el  texto y encima de el colocas un `textView`. Eso seria mas fácil y te ahorraría unos cuantos dolores de cabeza.

Comment: Se puede hacer eso en un linearLayout?

Comment: Seria mejor hacerlo en un relativeLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las propiedades a tener en cuenta son:

- `android:layout_alignTop="@+id/boton"` alinea el TextView con el borde superior del botón
- `android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/boton"` alinea el TextView con el borde izquierdo del botón
- `android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"` aleja el TextView 20dp del borde izquierdo del boton.
- `android:layout_marginTop="20dp"` aleja el TextView 15dp del borde superior del boton.
- `android:elevation="2dp"` eleva el TextView 2dp. Esto es para que el TextView quede por encima del boton.

Juega con los valores de las propiedades `android:layout_marginLeft` y `android:layout_marginTop` para colocar el `TextView` en la posición que desees.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/boton"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#ccc"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hola como"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/boton" 
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/boton" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar dentro de tu `Textview` :

```
android:layout_marginTop="numero_enterodp"
```

Vas acomodando tu control hasta quedar alineando como deseas. Otra alternativa es utilizar un `Relative` es mas facil controlar las posiciones.

Si quieres entender mas puedes revisar la siguiente [explicación](http://android4beginners.com/2013/07/lesson-2-2-how-to-use-margins-and-paddings-in-android-layout/).(enlace en ingles)

Para "superponer" la vista puedes usar dentro de tu `Textview`:

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@id/id_imagenView"
```

Comment: Lo alineo pero queda la imagen en frente y el texto del TextView por detras, alguna forma de superponer el texto?

Comment: Editada la respuesta @DVertel

Answer (score 0):

Lo he solucionado agregando un paddingBottom de 30dp y ha quedado alineado perfectamente, gracias a los que comentaron.